# WordPress custom page templates reads from subdirectory

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I need guides please, as I am new to this.

So I installed WordPress locally and managed to create my custom theme with just the basic theme content.

Theme Directory: `wp-content/themes/custom-theme/`

In this directory I wish to create sub-directories (`content/home`, `content/blog` ...), and then I want my pages to read from this sub-directories, ect.

The homepage will read from `custom-theme\content\home` with the home directory folder including files like `page.php`.

I did already manage to create a template file called `page-home.php` which I linked as a template Parent page to the new page I created in wordpress. My problem is the files in that directory do not get hooked.

Code from `page-home.php`

```
     <?php 
          /*Template Name: Home - Parent Page */
     ?>

     <?php get_header(); ?>
         <div id="content-main">
     <?php $contentSrc = "content/home"; ?>

    <script>
        window.contentSrc = '<?php echo $contentSrc; ?>';
    </script>

    <?php //get_template_part("page-home"); ?>
    </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is something I've tried. And it then should hook the pages from sub directory content/home .

Code from: `content/home/page.php`

```
   <div id="home">
     <div class="hook" data-hook="home-info"></div>
     <div class="hook" data-hook="home-navi"></div>
   </div>
```

This needs a function/js to work, but its just the idea of what I need and what I want to make happen.

Any links to guidelines for this or tips would be much appreciated, I have looked everywhere and i just do not find any easy or exact topic based on my question.

Maybe there is just a very easy way of doing it, i am interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the tools that WordPress offers is [`get_template_part();`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

However, this requires you do use Wordpress' loop on the page calling this function.

### From the docs:

> Includes the named template part for a theme or if a name is specified then a specialized part will be included. If the theme contains no {slug}.php file then no template will be included.
>
> The template is included using require, not require_once, so you may include the same template part multiple times.

### Using with theme subfolders

To use this function with subfolders in your theme directory, simply prepend the folder name before the slug. For example, if you have a folder called “partials” in your theme directory and a template part called “content-page.php” in that sub-folder, you would use get_template_part() like this:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'page' ); ?>
```

### Using PHP

You can also use a simple `include()`/`require()`/etc. With the following code:

```
<?php include( get_template_directory() . '/content/myfile.php'); ?>
```

This particular example uses the [`get_template_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) function to find your custom theme path. An alternative (but still useful) function to use is [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory)

**Additional Resources**

- [Theme Development @ WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)
- [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-development)
- [Generic Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=making+a+wordpress+theme)